# Project root as web root (instead of wwwroot)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET Core 3.1. By default, the `wwwroot` directory is the default web root directory.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // defaults to wwwroot
}
```

It can be changed to any directory including the project root

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // serves static files from the project root
    });
}
```

Having the project root as my web root would suit my current project structure. Is there a good reason why I shouldn't use the project root as the web root?

Comment: Your project root is going to contain files that should not be served out as static files. Why then do you want to serve the project root out? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: @mason As far as I can tell, my application doesn't serve files that I don't want made public. For example, if I try to access `appsettings.json`, my application returns a 404. My `.cs` files are not served. I'll add this to my question. Can you elaborate on what files I do not want to serve and I'll do some tests?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a reasonable question right?

Comment: If your server were ever misconfigured, or a file was placed in your project directory that you don't want being served (perhaps a config.json containing API keys)  then someone could access that. It just doesn't make any sense to change it to your project directory. It's change for change's sake - it has no benefit. Some thought about the consequences would lead you to this conclusion.

Comment: @mason I understand that if a sensitive file were placed in the root dirctory (or child of) then it would be available publicly. This is no different from placing a sensitive file in wwwroot. I'd be concerned if anything sensitive was placed outside of appsettings.json anyway. For the server being misconfigured - I would imagine that the default static files setup is an opt-in? I.e. only certain file extensions are sent staright to the client. Not sure how it could be misconfigured.

Comment: You are free to look at how the server is setup if you want. By default, IIS, if that's your server, is configured to serve JSON files for example. You have not made a clear use case why you would want to do this and the potential negatives are quite large.

Comment: @mason Turns out I got the code wrong above. It was still serving files from wwwroot. The `RequestPath = ""` does nothing. I need to change the `FileProvider` property. I'm going to delete this question in a couple of days unless someone else does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After some flawed testing (see comments under the answer) it turns out there is a very good reason not to do this. Your `appsettings.json` file will be available to anyone who wants it.